# coalesce and a case statement - explanation?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a query that doesn't seem to be doing what it's supposed to since being transferred from one SSRS server to another, and the following line in part of the where statement *appears* to be where the difference is, or at least from what I can find.

```
where COALESCE(field, -1) = CASE field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
```

I know it's probably a bit generic but can anyone shed any light on what this may be doing? I've read up on coalesce and gather that it finds the first non-null value from the specified list of fields, but I don't understand what the '-1' does there.

I hope it's not too general a question and that someone can give me a clue as to what it may be doing

Comment: If `field` is NULL the expression `COALESCE(field, -1)` is evaluated to `-1`. Then on the right side of the comparison, `field` is not equal to `1` so the case statement will return `-1`. So, if the `field` is NULL the condition is true, if the `field` is not NULL, `field` is compared with 0 or -1.

Comment: @gotqn so am I right in thinking that if `field` is `1`, the statement as a whole treats it as `0`, and if `field` is null, it treats it as `-1`?

Comment: To be precisely correct, it is a CASE expression.. not a statement :)

Comment: @laurencemadill Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @laurencemadill What are the possible values for field?  Can you give any context for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without context it's difficult to give a truly helpful answer.
At first glance it looks as though it could be rewritten much more simply from this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
```

to this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
```

If that is true then basically you are saying that if the field is null or the field equals -1 then the condition is true otherwise it's false.

Here are some tests to try to prove this:

```
-- Original
DECLARE @field INT
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
SET @field = -1
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
SET @field = 0
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
SET @field = 1
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
SET @field = 2
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END
SET @field = 3
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = CASE @field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END

--Rewritten
DECLARE @field INT
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
SET @field = -1
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
SET @field = 0
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
SET @field = 1
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
SET @field = 2
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
SET @field = 3
SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@field, -1) = -1
```

Both sets of queries in this test give the same results, but as I said without context and realistic test data it's difficult to know if there was a reason why the query was written in the way that it originally was.

Here is another example from a different perspective, using a LEFT JOIN:

```
DECLARE @MainTable AS TABLE(ident INT)
DECLARE @PossibleNullTable AS TABLE(mainIdent INT, field INT)

INSERT INTO @MainTable(ident) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @MainTable(ident) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @MainTable(ident) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @MainTable(ident) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @MainTable(ident) VALUES(5)

INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(1,-1)
INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(1,0)

INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(2,0)
INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(3,1)
INSERT INTO @PossibleNullTable(mainIdent, field) VALUES(5,-1)

--Original
SELECT *
FROM @MainTable mt
LEFT JOIN @PossibleNullTable pnt
    ON mt.ident = pnt.mainIdent
WHERE COALESCE(field, -1) = CASE field WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE -1 END

--Original Result 
ident   mainIdent   field
1       1           -1
4       NULL        NULL
5       5           -1

--Rewritten
SELECT *
FROM @MainTable mt
LEFT JOIN @PossibleNullTable pnt
    ON mt.ident = pnt.mainIdent
WHERE COALESCE(field, -1) = -1

--Rewritten Result 
ident   mainIdent   field
1       1           -1
4       NULL        NULL
5       5           -1
```

Again both queries in this test give the same results.

Comment: The overall query is fairly complex. The one I'm using is like a procedure within a stored procedure, the parent procedure uses the 1 or 0 to determine whether to write records to the database, the nested procedure that this statement is in lists the courses, but only if records have been entered to the db. If they have, it won't show them in this report again. I gather that it is part of the where statement that excludes those.

Comment: ...also, I've changed it round a bit now and it appears to be working. I still don't get why it had been working on a previous reporting server though!

Comment: @laurencemadill: The way servers/database handle nulls can very depending on their properties, I haven't looked into it very far and it's probably a question better asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.  Don't forget to mark an answer if somebody here helped, or put your own solution up if you have resolved it yourself, so that other people can benefit from your discovery.

Answer (score 1):

> the first non-null value from the specified list of fields

This means the list of fields between the parenthesis. For instance:

```
COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,-1)
```

means that if `col1` is not null then use this, else check `col2`. If `col2` is null then check `col3`. If that is null too then use -1 as the value.

In your example, `COALESCE(field, -1)` is equivalent to `ISNULL(field, -1)`

In my example `COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,-1)` is equivalent to `ISNULL(ISNULL(ISNULL(col1, col2), col3), -1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complex expression used in where clause, that suggests

use field column, `replace NULL values with -1` & `compare` all these values of field column `with the case expression` such as,

here at first, we have to consider that there is `no null value in field column` as we have `replaced all null with -1 using coalesce().`

then in case statement, `if the values is 1 then it is replace by 0`. So `0 is checked with coalesce(field,-1)`, `if it is also 0, then expression is true else false`.

Similar for field value -1 using case.